# Difference between composer prefer-dist and prefer-source?

Tags: php, composer-php

Looking at the help for PHP Composer's `install` command, I see the following two options

```
$ composer help install
Options:
 --prefer-source            Forces installation from package sources when possible, including VCS information.
 --prefer-dist              Forces installation from package dist even for dev versions.
```

What's a "dist" installation?  I poked around the composer site and Google but there didn't seem to be anything that addressed this (So I assume it's something core and obvious to folks familiar with Composer — apologies for the newbie question)

I'm assuming `--prefer-source` is where Composer will ask Packagist for the repository location, and then checkout/clone/export/etc. the project itself.

If so, then where does `--prefer-dist` download from?  What does it download?

Comment: I'm *completely guessing* that "dist" is short for "distribution"

Comment: @nickb That's what the docs online have led me to believe — but nothing seems to describe what a distribution is.

Comment: Check [their example for Smarty](http://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#package-2). It looks like "dist" would be a stable distribution that the dependency is publishing, where "source" would be a latest snapshot, potentially directly from their source control.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

According to http://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md, the `--prefer-source` option will prefer to create a package directory that is a "version control repository". This is equivalent to you typing:

```
$ git clone ...
```

or

```
$ svn checkout ...
```

The `--prefer-dist` option will prefer to create a non-"version control repository", which is equivalent to you typing:

```
$ git clone ... ; rm -fr dir/.git
```

or

```
$ svn export ...
```

Also, you can define separate repos for `source` and `dist` in your `composer.json`. Here's an example:

```
{
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "package",
            "package": {
                "name": "joshuaclayton/blueprint-css",
                "version": "master",
                "source": {
                    "url": "git://github.com/joshuaclayton/blueprint-css.git",
                    "type": "git",
                    "reference": "master",
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "package",
            "package": {
                "name": "fiftyone/mobi-lite-php",
                "version": "2013.03.06",
                "dist": {
                    "url": "http://iweb.dl.sourceforge.net/project/fiftyone/51Degrees.mobi-Lite-2013.03.06.php.zip",
                    "type": "zip"
                },
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

NOTE: for whatever reason, when I use `--prefer-dist`, I sometimes get errors such as

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract in ...
```

which do not appear when I use `--prefer-source`. For this reason, I only use `--prefer-source`, until I figure out the cause of this issue.

Comment: When you get those errors do `composer dump-autoload`.

Comment: `--prefer-dist` is not equivalent to a git checkout minus the `.git` directory, although it is close enough. As you noted, you can separately define the source and distribution URL of a package; if you don't, it will result in a git archive instead of a git checkout. That means the [`export.ignore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes#_export_ignore) option of `.gitattributes` will be honored - if the project bothered to set it properly, unit tests and similar files that are not necessary (and sometimes even risky) in a production site will usually be omitted.

Comment: Also, `--prefer-dist` is a bit faster and does not require Git to be installed.

Comment: Thanks for your response, it helped a lot. Note: structure of repositories has slightly changed: https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#package-2.

Comment: Is it possible to remove the note with the error - this seems entirely unrelated to the question and I assume is resolved now - it's been almost 10 years.

Answer (score 33):

I don't admire, or even approve the provided answer, as it **does not address the question**. So despite of it being a bit too old, I am posting this answer for any further reference to this question.

---

## Basics:

Normally composer deals with **tags** (like `1.2.7`), but that is not the case all the time. You may also require a **branch** (like `dev-master`) as a dependency.

- If you want composer to require a **tag**, it just copies the files on your local (somewhere in your `vendor` directory).
- If you want composer to checkout a **branch** instead of a tag, there is chance (composer's rational assumption), you want to develop it (thus making changes), so composer **clones** the repository on your local (again, somewhere in the `vendor` directory).

---

## So, what?!

#### Question:

What if you want to require a **tag**, but still be able to develop it on your local?

#### Answer:

use `--prefer-source` along with your `composer require` or `composer update` commands:

```
composer require symfony/symfony:3.4.* --prefer-source
```

#### Question:

What if you want to require a most new development **branch**, but you just want to get the new stuff and don't want to get engaged in its development?

#### Answer:

use `--prefer-dist` along with your `composer require`, `composer update` commands:

```
composer require symfony/symfony:dev-master --prefer-dist
```

Comment: Small typo `--prefer-srouce` should be `--prefer-source`

Comment: And 'dist' is default if you omit those flags?

Comment: You can't specify an individual package with `composer install`. If you want to specify source vs dist at a package level use `preferred-install` in composer.json

Comment: Maybe the accepted answer has been updated. How does it not answer the question?

Comment: @FrankRobertAnderson I think you answered your own question by yourself!

Comment: Looks like the suggest an edit queue is full. Maybe if you removed that whole part about how **bad** the accepted answer is a question like mine wouldn't be needed.

Answer (score 10):

As clearly stated in [Composer's Documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md):

> In fact, internally Composer sees **every version** as a **separate package**. While this distinction does not matter when you are using Composer, it's quite important when you want to change it.

and,

> **Dist**: The dist is a *packaged version of the package data*. Usually a released version, *usually a stable release*.
>
> **Source**: The source is used for development. This will *usually originate from a source code repository, such as git*. You can fetch this when you want to modify the downloaded package.

so,

> Packages can supply either of these, or even both. Depending on certain factors, such as user-supplied options and stability of the package, one will be preferred.

If you're checking out a branch, it's assumed that you want to work on the branch and Composer actually clones the repo into the correct place in your vendor directory.

For tags, it just copies the right files without actually cloning the repo.

Comment: I did `php composer.phar require phpmailer/phpmailer` and from the response it seems it tried to download from dist but zip commands were missing. So it went on and tried to download from source which succeeded. I wonder if that means that when it downloads from dist it gets a zipped file but from source it does not?