# Should I use --prefer-dist for production?

Tags: composer-php, production-environment

When I do `composer install` on the production system, should I use the flag `--prefer-dist`?

`--no-dev` is recommended, since it prevents the installation of packages that are only needed during development. But what is with `--prefer-dist`? This flag makes that the installed packages are without VCS stuff, as I read in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16205808/57091). I assume that I don't need this on a production machine. Am I right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The dist file (e.g. tar archive) is usually quicker to download than cloning the repository (which is the case when using `--prefer-source`).

The main difference is that cloning the repository will give you everything, while a lib maintainer can create the dist itself. This means that they might not include the tests in the dist file for instance. That's why people suggest using `--prefer-dist`, as it *might* end up downloading less files.

Anyway, `--prefer-dist` isn't really needed as Composer always defaults to the dist file when downloading a *stable* dependency. As it's really a bad practice to have unstable dependencies running in production, you probably end up downloading the dist for all packages anyway (unless you use `--prefer-source` of course).