# Configure Composer dependency to use path for source and git for dist

Tags: git, composer-php

I have a project that uses another GitHub project of mine as a dependency. I have two requirements for my Composer configuration for this dependency:

- When I'm working locally, I need `composer install --prefer-source` to [symlink to my local copy of the dependency](https://medium.com/pvtl/local-composer-package-development-47ac5c0e5bb4) so I can run `git` commands inside the dependency.
- When my build process is running, I need `composer install --prefer-dist` to install directly from the GitHub repository with no symlinking.

Previously I had used the following inside `composer.json` to achieve the first requirement:

```
  "require": {
    "narthur/natlib": "@dev"
  },
  "repositories": [
    {
      "type": "path",
      "url": "../natlib",
      "options": {
        "symlink": true
      }
    }
  ]
```

After some work, I came up with this, which manages to satisfy the second requirement:

```
  "require": {
    "narthur/natlib": "@dev"
  },
  "repositories": [
    {
      "type": "package",
      "package": {
        "name": "narthur/natlib",
        "version": "2019.06.20",
        "dist": {
          "type": "zip",
          "url": "https://github.com/narthur/natlib/archive/master.zip"
        },
        "source": {
          "type": "path",
          "url": "../natlib",
          "reference": "master",
          "options": {
            "symlink": true
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
```

This works great in CI. But when I delete my local `vendor/` dir and `composer.lock` file and run `composer install --prefer-source`, I get the following exception:

> [LogicException]
>     Downloader "Composer\Downloader\PathDownloader" is a dist type downloader and can not be used to download source for package narthur/natlib-2019.06.20.0

I tried separating them into two repository entries like this:

```
{
  "type": "path",
  "url": "../natlib",
  "options": {
    "symlink": true
  }
},
{
  "type": "package",
  "package": {
    "name": "narthur/natlib",
    "version": "2019.06.20",
    "dist": {
      "type": "zip",
      "url": "https://github.com/narthur/natlib/archive/master.zip"
    }
  }
}
```

This works locally, symlinking the dependency, but fails in CI, [because Composer stops at the first matching repository entry](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#repositories):

> Order is significant here. When looking for a package, Composer will look from the first to the last repository, and pick the first match.

How can I configure Composer to behave the way I want, such that locally the `--prefer-source` flag will symlink the dependency, while in CI the `--prefer-dist` flag will pull in the repository?

Information I've found:

- [Difference between composer prefer-dist and prefer-source?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16205808/937377)
- [Loading a package from a VCS repository](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#loading-a-package-from-a-vcs-repository)
- [Local Composer Package Development](https://medium.com/pvtl/local-composer-package-development-47ac5c0e5bb4)

Comment: You could work around the mentioned limit for dist repositories (having to specify the location of the archive) by specyfing the release url for your github-repository, e.g. `https://github.com/narthur/natlib/releases/latest`. Does that help?

Comment: @dbrumann Yes! That helped me fix the CI part of this. I've updated my question to show what I have now. Unfortunately, it's still not symlinking the dependency locally when I use `--prefer-source`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized my requirements were probably unnecessary. Since my dependency is hosted on GitHub, I can pull it the same way locally and remotely, and make changes to the dependency inside its vendor folder, pushing back to GitHub from there.

Here's what I'm using now:

```
  "require": {
    "narthur/natlib": "@dev"
  },
  "repositories": [
    {
      "type": "vcs",
      "url": "https://github.com/narthur/natlib"
    }
  ]
```

One gotcha I ran into when making this shift was that I initially tried going with a package-type repository instead of a simple vcs-type one. This didn't work because [it caused Composer to ignore the dependency's `composer.json` file, preventing it from being autoloaded](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47511301/937377). After switching to the simple vcs entry above, everything works perfectly.